# Finding directional derivatives that exist

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $$g(x,y,z)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy+xz+yz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, & \text{if } xi+yj+zk \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{if } xi+yj+zk = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Use the definition of the directional derivative to determine for which unit vectors $v=ui+vj+wk$ the directional derivative $D_vg(0)$ exists

The derivatives at 0 exist but are all 0 across all variables, I believe. I don't understand how to find the unit vectors however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D_vg(0)$ is supposed to be following: $$\nabla g.\frac{u}{|u|}  = \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x },\frac{\partial g}{\partial y } , \frac{\partial g}{\partial z }\right).\frac{ui+vj+wk}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2}}$$
Now you can substitute 0,0,0.

Comment: since 0 will always be the result of that, does that mean that any unit vector can work?